# Laravel show Error 42000 when I run function to generate statistics

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel. I use in my project Laravel 5.8.

I have schema:

```
Schema::create('statistics', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->text('agent')->nullable();
            $table->date('date')->nullable();
            $table->ipAddress('ip');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->default(0);
            $table->bigInteger('quest_id')->default(0);
            $table->string('browser', 70)->nullable();
            $table->string('platform', 70)->nullable();
            $table->string('language', 12)->nullable();
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });
```

and I have function:

```
Statistics::select('id', 'ip', 'date', 'user_id')->where('date', '>=', $dateFrom )->where('date', '<=', $dateTo )->where('user_id', $id)->groupBy('ip')->get();
```

When I have enable strict mode in database.php I have error:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'db.statistics.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `id`, `ip`, `date`, `user_id` from `statistics` where `date` >= 2019-10-15 00:00:00 and `date` <= 2019-10-22 00:00:00 and `user_id` = 2 group by `ip`)
```

I like strict mode.

How can I repair my function?

Comment: The error is pretty obvious. That column isn't in group by.. Also you need to add all columns used in "select" in group by clause. Or don't use groupby at all, as you don't have any aggregate function like max, count, ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you group by date you basically squash rows together, imagine the following row structure.

```
id | ip | date | user_id
1, 192, 2019-01-01, 1
2, 192, 2019-01-02, 1
3, 192, 2019-01-03, 1
4, 193, 2019-01-04, 1
```

Will result in the following result

```
id | ip | date | user_id
n, 192, n, n
n, 132, n, n
```

With n being variables SQL can't decide on. That's why your query is failing, because these fields will basically represent multiple values. To get columns into these places, you will need to use an aggregate function. A solution would be to use Max, Min or Sum functions. But normally when you do group by it is to summarize a column into one number, like a total amount of tries or sales. So i would expect you to do something similar to.

```
Statistics::select('ip', DB::raw('count(id) as tries'))
    ->where('date', '>=', $dateFrom )
    ->where('date', '<=', $dateTo )
    ->where('user_id', $id)
    ->groupBy('ip')
    ->get();
```

Comment: It is the same query as you posted, then your date logic or user id check is wrong the important part of it was the select you gotten wrong and produced the error.

Comment: Sorry. I found. In result I have: attributes: array:2 [▼
        "ip" => "1.224.190.227"
        "tries" => 3
      ]. How can I add date, user_id etc. to this result?

Comment: there is no date, as clearly described in the answer you are squashing rows with group by, why do you need group by in the first place?

Comment: This function return Statistics::select('ip', DB::raw('count(id) as tries'))
            ->where('date', '>=', $dateFrom )
            ->where('date', '<=', $dateTo )
            ->where('user_id', $id)
            ->groupBy('ip')
            ->distinct('ip')
            ->get(); -return me all visits. It's work fine. I need count with unique visits

Comment: You are counting unique visits, But the answer fixed your error, so please accept it as the answer. And the rest of the data does not make sense in this context, as there is no single date that represents each row.